# Taking the values inside a if condition to an int array - java

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a few **checkboxes** in my **JSP** page and I'm taking out their values like this from a servlet.

```
if (f.getFieldName().equals("checkboxVal")) {
  Genres = f.getString();
}
```

This condition will executes several times, there is **no exact number**.I want to assign each Genres values to an `int` array.How can this be done.

Comment: A better way would be for a servlet on the server side to populate a map of string/int pairs and pass it to the JSP.  Logic like this in UI is hard to code and maintain.  It only grows over time.  Move that to the server side where it's easier to do.  Better encapsulation of that f class would be the right way.  Let it tell you its state.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a request/session level attribute and use it in your code. Like:

```
List<Integer> list = ...
request.setAttribute("Name", list);
...
//in your code
List<Integer> name = request.getAttribute("Name");
if (f.getFieldName().equals("checkboxVal")) {
     name.add(f.getString());//assuming this getString returns number else you might need to convert it.. I would have just used list within f object rather than maintaining list
}
```